# Stopwatch (chronometre) doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt

I make a stopwatch (chronometre) in python using the library pyqt, but I have a problem when I press the reset button and then the start button, I see the time increase of two, and repeat the process I see that increase in threes and so on.
   I do not understand why this happens. I hope some can help me.
   This is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4 import uic


class Cronometro(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("cronometro.ui", self)

        self.sec = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()

        self.set_time()

        # Conexion
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.btnReset.clicked.connect(self.reset)
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def start(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.counter)
        self.timer.start(1000)

    def reset(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.sec = 0

    def counter(self):
        self.sec += 1
        self.set_time()

    def is_timer_active(self):
        return self.timer.isActive()

    def set_time(self):
        hora = self.sec / 3600
        minutos = (self.sec % 3600) / 60
        segundos = (self.sec % 3600) % 60
        self.label.setText("%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hora, minutos, segundos))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ventana = Cronometro()
ventana.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here, in your `start` method:

```
    def start(self):
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.counter)
        self.timer.start(1000)
```

Every time you start the timer, you connect the timer's `timeout` signal to your `counter` method.  So if you start the timer twice, there are two connections from the timer to your `counter` method, so the counter method gets called twice on every tick of the timer.

The fix is fairly straightforward: move the line

```
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.counter)
```

into your `__init__` method, so that the connection is only ever made once.